# SQL sum group by date and id

Tags: sql

Suppose you have result set such as:

```
DATE          ID    cost    
---------------------------------------
 01/01/2011    1     10      
 01/01/2011    1     10      
 01/01/2011    2     10      
 01/01/2011    2     10
```

I want a way to sum the values on cost but only once for every distinct ID so that when i group by date I get a result such as

```
DATE                ID1cost   ID2cost
01/01/2011         20             20
```

Comment: Tag dbms used, you've already got one product specific answer.

Comment: Do you have limit IDs or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    "Date",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN cost ELSE 0 END) AS "ID1Cost",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN cost ELSE 0 END) AS "ID2Cost"
FROM tbl
GROUP BY "Date"
```

Comment: ANSI SQL and almost all products but SQL Server have double quotes instead of square brackets, e.g. `"Date"` instead of `[Date]`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it was directed to OP (who didn't tag dbms...), and other less experienced SQL programmers.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server PIVOT. Hope you don't want dynamic PIVOT.

```
SELECT Date, [1] AS ID1cost, [2] AS ID2Cost
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('01/01/2011', 1, 10), ('01/01/2011', 1, 10), ('01/01/2011', 2, 10), ('01/01/2011', 2, 10)) AS T(Date ,ID, Cost)
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Cost)
    FOR ID IN ([1], [2])
) AS P
```